# WebRTC connection fails on Cellular Data

Tags: java, android, node.js, webrtc

I am trying to create an android application with WebRTC using these projects:

[AndroidRTC](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC)

Which uses this repository: [io.prinstine.libjingle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjingle/)

This project is working well when two clients are connected to the net over wifi but it doesnt work when one of the clients is connected via cellular data.

I tried to find the source to see what is going on an I found this static class:

```
public static class Options {
    // Keep in sync with webrtc/base/network.h!
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_ETHERNET = 1 << 0;
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_WIFI = 1 << 1;
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_CELLULAR = 1 << 2;
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_VPN = 1 << 3;
    static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_LOOPBACK = 1 << 4;

    public int networkIgnoreMask;
  }
```

And I have found this line of code which refers to a native method that uses this class:

```
public void setOptions(Options options) {
    nativeSetOptions(nativeFactory, options);
  }

public native void nativeSetOptions(long nativeFactory, Options options);
```

The question is how can I enable connection over cellular data? or I would appreciate it if you would help me to find the source of the native methods used in this project to better understand the structure.

Comment: What sort of stun and turn servers are you utilizing? At what point does the connection fail?

Comment: I don't have any TURN servers but I have a stun server that i found googling which is called stuntman and the stun server provided by google.

Comment: And i don't think it ever fails because it doesn't make any connection to fail. What should i do to test if connection is made.

Comment: Use your sdpobserver to monitor the connection status. You should also check to make sure that the application is even communicating with your signalling server. Also, I just remembered, some providers may actually block media like this(even if the connection is successful).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I observed all the sdp methods with a log but there is no difference between the one over wifi and the one over cellular. What exactly should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

from what you have said i think the library your using is connecting over wifi on default, so if you plan on using cellular data then i think you should make a test for that then use the setoptions method found within the library else the library or your app wil keep trying to make a connection over wifi.

Comment: But how is it doing this and how can I change the default method? I didn't find anything within the project that is related to wifi or mobile data...

Comment: that method you spoke of above should be used  the public void setoptions then set it to mobile network...e.g `ClassObject.setOptions(options.ADAPTER_TYPE_CELLULAR)` remember options.adaptertype is a static variable so its not being instantiated